# Facebook Registration | Custom Fields Not Returning

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to create a Facebook Registration process for our website that will create an account for the user in our CRM - to this end I require the use of a few custom fields in the registration form.

I have the registration form appearing properly on the site, however, when I process the signed_request the JSON only returns the decoded standard items and not my custom fields:

```
{ 
 "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256", 
 "code": "2.AQDp0sgWRw3TWrII.3600.1330650000.1100001862544007|LwjvMjADtPxaIzxizYuIivNdi7w",
 "issued_at": 1330644064, 
 "user_id": "<my user id>" 
}
```

This is a .NET implementation but I am not using the Facebook C# SDK as none of the documentation seems to be available anymore on their site and I'm just not clever enough to figure it out. I tried using the new 6.x beta of the Facebook C# SDK and the Facebook.Client() parse method but didn't have any luck determining what to do with it once the thing was parsed.

So - this stolen code is what I used to get the results posted above:

```
        //client_payload = the signed_request from Facebook
        string[] sB64String = client_payload.Split('.');
        string payload = client_payload.Replace((sB64String[0] + "."), string.Empty);

        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
        var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        response.write(Convert.ToString(jObject)); // rw for debugging
```

Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this on my own by modifying the way I was going about it.

I ended up using the  tag and client side cookie as found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/

All of my custom fields end up in the cookie that I can then parse and send to my .NET webservice. Kind of a round-about way of doing it but it's getting the job done now.